# How do I enter the backticks for contexts as inline code?

Tags: support, faq, markdown

Contexts have backticks, which conflict with the normal way to enter inline code.  How do I enter an inline context, since the initial approach:

```
`System``
```

doesn't work ( `System`` ).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is so common in Mathematica that I suggest this should be specially included in the editor help or the FAQ on this site.  Let me list the most common usages:

- Contexts, for example, `` Global` ``.

  Markdown: ``` ``Global` `` ``` (note the space before the closing ``` `` ```)
- Precision of numbers, for example, `` 2.3`40 ``.

  Markdown: ``` ``2.3`40`` ```
- Accuracy of numbers, for example, ``` 2.3``3 ```.

  Markdown: ```` ```2.3``3``` ````
- `StringForm` expressions, for example, ``` StringForm["x = ``", x] ```

  Markdown: ```` ```StringForm["x = ``", x]``` ````

  And here the question comes up, how to include a double backtick (``` `` ```) in inline code?  **Generally, if you want to include `n` consecutive backticks, surround the inline code span with `n+1` backticks.**  For this reason, if the inline code has a backtick at the very end, you need to put a space after it.  Don't worry, [this space will be stripped when the MarkDown is rendered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117422/how-can-i-write-inline-code-ending-in-a-backtick).

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the HTML markup `<code>...</code>`. This has the advantage that you can bold and italicise inside it, like so:

```
<code>f[x_*Pattern*]:= 50.`**watch out**</code>
```

Results in

`` f[x_Pattern]:= 50.` watch out ``

And as you can see, you don't need to count backticks.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12694/escaping-backticks-fails), you can use double backticks set off by spaces to surround a code snippet:

```
`` System` ``
```

produces `` System` ``.

Answer (score 3):

Backslashes before backticks seem to work too. For example,

```
`?Global\`*`
```

in the comment below:

Comment: `?Global\`*` It works in comments, but not in answers. Hmm...